# how to copy many directories to many destinations? (massive copy)

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, robocopy

I need to copy 3 folders to many destination (600+), I need to parallelize it.

For intance

```
C:\Data1   →    D:\Data1
C:\Data1   →    D:\Data2
C:\Data1   →    D:\Data3
D:\Data1   →    \\\VM1\c$\Data1
D:\Data2   →    \\\VM1\c$\Data2
D:\Data3   →    \\\VM1\c$\Data3
…
```

I constructed an object for it

```
[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    Source = 'C:\Data1'
    Dest = 'D:\Data1'
},
[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    Source = 'C:\Data1'
    Dest = 'D:\Data2'
},
[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    Source = 'C:\Data1'
    Dest = 'D:\Data3'
},
…
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call a Robocopy-Job for each couple but i limit the nomber of Process and number of RoboCopy-Thread.

```
function Copy-AsParallelJod {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
            [ValidateScript({ $_ | Test-Path })]
                [string]$Source,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
            [Alias('Dest')]
                [string]$Destination,
        $MaxRunningJob = 4,
        $MaxThreadByJob = 8
    )
    begin {
        $Start = Get-Date
        write-host (get-date $Start -format 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss') -Width 150 -back DarkGreen
         # get-job | Remove-Job -Force
    }
    process {
        while ((Get-Job -State Running  | ?{$_.Name -like "Copy_*"}).count -ge $MaxRunningJob) {

            # Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
            wait-Job -Name 'Copy_*' -Any | Receive-Job  -AutoRemoveJob -Wait
        }
        $WorkName = (($Destination.split('\'))[-2..-1]) -join(' ')

        Write-host 'Copy-Job',' : ',$Source.padleft(55),'  To  ',$Destination.padright(55),'  @ ',(get-date -format 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss') red

        Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
            param($Source, $Dest, $log="/LOG+:C:\MAJ\Robocopy.log.txt", $MaxThread)
            $Start = Get-Date
            New-Item -Path $dest -type Directory -Force | Out-Null
            [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.Priority = 'Lowest'
            $PathIdentity = ($Dest.split('\')[-2..-1]) -join('\')

            Robocopy $Source $Dest /E $log /TEE /MT:$MaxThread /S /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:3 /W:2 | Out-Null
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

            $Time =  (Get-Date) - $start
            $Time = "$($time.Hours)h $("$($time.Minutes)".padleft(2,'0'))m $("$($time.Seconds)".padleft(2,'0'))s"
        } -ArgumentList $Source,$Destination,"/LOG+:$(split-path $Destination)\RoboCopy($(get-date -format 'yyyy.MM.dd HH.mm'))-$WorkName.log.txt",$MaxThreadByJob -name Copy_$WorkName | Out-Null
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
    }
    end {
        Get-Job -Name 'Copy_*' | Receive-Job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait
        $Time =  (Get-Date) - $start
        $Time = "$($time.Hours)h $("$($time.Minutes)".padleft(2,'0'))m $("$($time.Seconds)".padleft(2,'0'))s"
        write-host "$(get-date -format 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss') [$Time]" -Width 150 -back DarkGreen
    }
}
```

and i call it like that

```
[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    Source = 'C:\Data1'
    Dest = 'D:\Data1'
},
[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    Source = 'C:\Data1'
    Dest = 'D:\Data2'
},
[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    Source = 'C:\Data1'
    Dest = 'D:\Data3'
} | Copy-AsParallelJod -MaxRunningJob 4 -MaxThreadByJob 8
```

Comment: Warning ! Very strong CPU, I/O disk and Network consumption !

Comment: this is beautiful.